# 4G Connection not working properly

Tags: mobile-data, carriers

A month or so ago, when I turned Mobile Data on the device did not connect to the Internet. I thought that it is a temporary issue with the carrier but it is still not working.

**Details of the issue:**

1. It doesn't display anything on the bar icon (on status bar) which shows the network connectivity.
2. I could connect to 4G using a workaround. When I disable 4G in connection settings, it successfully connects to 3G. (and shows H+ in the bar icon) When I turn on 4G again it successfully connects to 4G and shows 4G in the bar icon.
3. In `System --> About Phone --> Status  --> Network` it shows `Mobile Network: Disconnected` even though Mobile Data is on.

I tried pulling out and putting in the SIM card, switching SIM slots. I can't try the SIM card with an another phone, or an another SIM card with my phone as I don't have access for either for the time being.

Why is this happening? Is this an issue on carrier end or my phone? (it is still on warranty)

My device is Huawei P Smart+ running Android 8.1 (EMUI 8.2). Thank you!

Comment: Unless you can check with another SIM (or check the SIM in another phone), it's hard to tell. Meanwhile, you could check with your provider if the SIM is open for mobile data at all (it might be blocked in their system). It could also be a technical problem with the SIM itself, or with the phone. So if your carrier has a shop you can visit, I'd recommend that as they could check directly with another phone and SIM.

Comment: Okay, I'll try going to one of their outlets, and let you know what they said. Thank you for the reply! :)

Comment: Good luck! And remember you can [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) when you found out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the SIM card to a carrier outlet, and they said that it is a damaged SIM card and replaced it. Thanks @Izzy for the helpful comment! :)